# Does react-native init downloads package every time?

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native, npm-install

I recently started learning `react-native` also I am new to `node` and `npm`. When I create a new react-native project I noticed that it takes really long time for every project.

Shouldn't it be like after initialization of first project it should cache the downloaded packages and use it when I create other projects?

I looked at the option to install react-native globally as `npm install -g react-native` but then it throws error saying react-native is installed globally.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you initialise new project by `react-native-cli` (probably you have it installed globally) you create plain new directory with `package.json` and some additional starting files. After that in this directory is fired command `npm install` which fetches and install all modules defined in `pakcage.json` and put in `./node_modules/`.

If you like to have `npm install` step cached try to find out how to cache certain modules: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

Comment: So when I initialize new project again does react-native package is downloaded again or is it saved somewhere locally?

Comment: Exactly. Every time you run `npm install` NPM downloads and installs modules to `./node_modules/`. You can try to install with `-g` flag but this is antipatern and should be omitted.